# Removing Gridlines from Scanned Graph Paper Documents

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, image-processing, opencv3.0, pypdf

I would like to remove gridlines from a scanned document using Python to make them easier to read.

Here is a snippet of what we're working with:

[image: An example]

As you can see, there are inconsistencies in the grid, and to make matters worse the scanning isn't always square. Five example documents can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Pcnvo6Y0eEmuCJHHD3Uzxz8XKLh_ZcNP?usp=sharing).

I am open to whatever methods you may suggest for this, but using openCV and pypdf might be a good place to start before any more involved breaking out the machine learning techniques.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675334/how-to-remove-background-gridlines-from-scanned-images-with-opencv) addresses a similar question, but does not have a solution. The user posted the following code snippet which may be of interest (to be honest I have not tested it, I am just putting it here for your convivence).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rmv_lines(Image_Path):
    img = cv2.imread(Image_Path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
    minLineLength, maxLineGap = 100, 15
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
    for x in range(0, len(lines)):
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[x]:
        #if x1 != x2 and y1 != y2:
            cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),4)
    return cv2.imwrite('removed.jpg',img)
```

I would prefer the final documents be in pdf format if possible.

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Fair enough, should I delete this post? I am rather well versed in python, but not in image processing, so I was hoping I could get some assistance along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: I am the author of `pText`, the library being used in this answer)

I can help you part of the way (extracting the images from the PDF).

Start by loading the `Document`.
You'll see that I'm passing an extra parameter in the `PDF.loads` method.
`SimpleImageExtraction` acts like an `EventListener` for PDF instructions. Whenever it encounters an instruction that would render an image, it intercepts the instruction and stores the image.

```
with open(file, "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
    l = SimpleImageExtraction()
    doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle, [l])
```

Now that we have loaded the `Document`, and `SimpleImageExtraction` should have had a chance to work its magic, we can output the images. In this example I'm just going to store them.

```
    for i, img in enumerate(l.get_images_per_page(0)):
        output_file = "image_" + str(i) + ".jpg"
        with open(output_file, "wb") as image_file_handle:
            img.save(image_file_handle)
```

You can obtain pText either on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release), or using [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ptext-joris-schellekens/)
There are a ton more [examples](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md), check them out to find out more about working with images.